# Using Shopify 404 page for content

Tags: shopify, wordpress-rest-api

Shopify is quite restrictive about the ways that you can structure directories. For example all pages must have a url which looks like "`my-store.com/pages/my-page`".

Whilst there is no way around this in Shopify, I considered a workaround which would work like this.

1. Use javascript to check the URL queried when displaying the 404 page.
2. If URL queried = "my-url" connect to Wordpress Rest or graph QL API, query and then render desired content on the page.

For example, my-site.com/blog would return a 404 error, however javascript would run a function to get content when the URL ends in "/blog".

Although this would work from a technical point of view, I understand the server would still be giving a 404 error and this probably has wider implications? To what extent is this the case and is this an unviable solution?

Answer (score 1):

A really interesting idea.

The biggest issue I see will be SEO, since the URLS will still points to the 404 page and you won't be able to show the proper content with liquid, all of the pages will pull the 404 content and show as 404 pages in the google search.

---

That said I don't see any other major issues that will prevent you to use this with JS. It depends really how many type of pages will require this logic and how the JS logic is written, but as an idea I really like the possibility of it.

I will probably not recommend it to a client that wants a SEO optimized site, but for a personal one it seems like an interesting idea.